# Can you identify these mountain pieces

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

top view [image: top view]
side view
[image: side view]
profile view
[image: profile view]
2 x 2 bricks added for size reference
[image: 2 x2 bricks added for size reference]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Looks like:**

- [*Part #47847 - Rock Panel 2 x 4 x 6.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47847&name=Rock%20Panel%202%20x%204%20x%206&category=%5BRock%5D#T=C)

  [image: https://img.bricklink.com/ItemImage/PL/47847.png]
- *[Part #3684a - Slope 75 2 x 2 x 3 - Hollow Studs.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3684a#T=C)*

[image]

- *[Part #4460b - Slope 75 2 x 1 x 3 - Hollow Stud.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4460b&name=Slope%2075%202%20x%201%20x%203%20-%20Hollow%20Stud&category=%5BSlope%5D#T=C&C=1)*

  [image]

[image]